# Google Cloud SQL Storage

Tags: mysql

I created a MySQL instance and imported a 2 MB database last month. But now, when I check the total storage its shows as 2 GB. Is there any data other than my data is created in my database.

Please, advise.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Binary Data Logging was enabled, which increased the storage by 10x - 15x Google Cloud SQL Storage.